# Issues with Javascript closures and scope

Tags: javascript, d3.js, closures

Currently I've got the following:

```
function bar() {
    // Do fancy D3 stuff here

    function update(source) {
        // Do fancy D3 update
    }
}
```

I call `bar()` on the click of a button, but I'm going to need to have access to `update()` (as well as passing that an argument) from outside of `bar()`.  I've read as much as I can on closures, but I still can't get it to work quite yet.  I've seen stuff about assigning a function to the `window` object to make the internal function global, but I haven't gotten that to work either.

Comment: I don't know d3.js - would you have some example code that would prove closures to be useful in your opinion?

Comment: Why does `update` need to be declared inside `bar`?

Comment: Please show us the click handler, the external call to `update`, and the variables each of them needs to access (even if not working yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for but I don't see why you can't declare `update` outside of `bar`. Then you can access `update` from inside and outside `bar`.

**Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rcj29/)**

html:

```
<button onclick="bar()">Tree</button>
```

javascript:

```
function bar() {
    var p = document.createElement("h2");
    var pText = document.createTextNode("fancy D3 stuff in bar");
    p.appendChild(pText);
    document.body.appendChild(p);

    update("bar");
}

function update(source) {
    var p = document.createElement("h1");
    var pText = document.createTextNode("fancy D3 stuff in update called from " + source);
    p.appendChild(pText);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign the 'update' function to window you would do this.

```
function bar() {
    // Do fancy D3 stuff here

    var update = function (source) {
        // Do fancy D3 update
    }

    window.updateBar = update;

}
```

Comment: A simpler solution that would also work in interpreters that don't name their global object `window` (node.js etc.) is to simply declare the `update` without the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

if i can understand you well, you want something like that?

```
var a = {
    b : 0,
    set : function(input){
       b = input;         
    },
    get : function(){
        alert(b);
    }
}

a.set('34234');
a.get();
```